# Validar que un campo en yii 2 no permita escribir caracteres especiales como ,./ -"

Tags: javascript, yii2

Quiero validar dentro del crud generado por yii 2 lo siguiente:
- que el usuario no pueda escribir un carácter especial específico como ; o como "
Intentó implementarlo mediante JavaScript pero no me permite y adicional a esto tengo otra pregunta: 
Pregunta 2: ¿como puedo hacer para que yii2 valide una caja de texto o textfield, mientras estoy escribiendo, la validación la hace cuando salgo del campo de texto o cuando doy clic en el botón de guardar datos del form, pero no mienstras escribo, entonces cómo se hace?.. estoy trabajando recién con usuario y contraseña y el código que tengo es el que me da yii2 y la base que tengo es la que migra al instalar yii..

Comment: http://demos.krajee.com/
http://www.2amigos.us/open-source

Si quierse trabajar en Yii ve el repertorio de extensiones que ofrecen estás dos páginas e igual hay de muchos otros, cuando encuentres una, vuelves con una duda más concreta. De todos modos lo que quieres bien se puede hacer con fácil con js que trabaja del lado del cliente

Comment: Gracias por responder, si de hecho ya he revisado y trabajado con algunas extensiones, por ejemplo las de kartik, e incluso con algunas que generan crud, pero ninguna me ha servido en lo que quiero, ya reformular mi pregunta por qué de hecho no estaba clara.

Comment: ¿Y qué intentaste? Por favor agrega tu código, por más que no funcione, dentro de la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Con respecto a su primera pregunta en las reglas de validación del form quedaría algo así:

```
['ejemplo', 'match', "pattern" => "/^[a-záéíóúñ\s;?\"?]+$/i", "message" => "No permitido"],
```

Con el atributo pattern agregas lo que quieres permitir, en ese caso SI se permite `;` y el `"`, en caso de que lo borres solo permitirá letras en minúscula.

Con respecto a su 2 pregunta puedes usar ajax, aunque no se si en el momento que escribes va validando, inténtalo a ver si te funciona.